# Don't know template parameter types when casting a void* to a templated type

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I am using the pthreads library and when I create a thread I am giving it the pointer to an object that is a templated type.

I'm inexperienced with templates (just read about them today) and need to cast the void* parameter from the method declaration the pthread runs to the templated type so I can access its members. In short something that looks like so:

In short something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    void aMember() { ... }
};

int main() {
    A<int> a;

    pthread_create(..., ..., &run, &a);

    ...
    ...
    ...
}

void *run(void *arg) {
    (A*)arg->aMember()
}
```

My problem is I get all these errors that I don't know how to rectify. I do in fact understand the errors but don't know the solution. Here are the errors:

error: expected primary-expression before ( token
error: missing template arguments before * token
error: expected primary-expression before ) token
error: expected `)' before 'info'

I just don't see how I could ever know the argument types of A when I am casting to it once in the thread?

I'm using the C++ Templates: The Complete Guide book as a reference/learning resource and must say I am over whelmed with all the info needed to fully understand templates. I was wondering if anyone had a solution to the problem, or could point me in the direction of another resource that might provide answers.

As always I appreciate your help greatly.

**EDIT/UPDATE**

It seems that adding context to my problem might help. Alternatively maybe someone can provide a different solution using a different design.

I am using libcurl to make HTTP Requests and depending on the Response I receive I will create an object of a specific type (thus the templates). I create a new thread for each Request I would like to make so that everything runs Asynchronously.

Comment: Sorry. I should of added context to my problem earlier but Im using the pthreads library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
void *run(void *arg) {
    static_cast<A<T>*>(arg)->aMember();
}

int main() {
    A<int> a;

    pthread_create(..., ..., &run<int>, &a);

    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

This does, like your original code snippet, rely on extern "C++" calling convention to be the same as what your pthread library uses. I'm not sure whether POSIX has any requirements that those be the same, but if they differ you are out of luck, because you cannot give function templates C language linkage.

Comment: I think I am running into the linkage problem you mentioned as it in pthread_create it says undefined reference to void* MyClass::run<std::basic_string<.....>>(void*) when I obviously call run using <std::string>

Comment: @Chris when you say `&run<std::string>`, you need to have the definition of `run` in scope.

Comment: Awesome, I wish I had found this thread when I ran into the same issue with type casting for objects in pthread function helpers. But one question are you able to pass templates into pthread_create?

Answer (score 2):

Class templates are not classes, they *generate* classes when given template arguments. Likewise, you cannot make a cookie from a cookie cutter until you supply cookie dough. Casting to `A` is meaningless.

It's hard to say what the right solution is since [you haven't said what you're trying to accomplish, just the step you're taking](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). If `run` should only ever work on one type, you know the template argument will always be the same; you could do this:

```
void *run(void *arg) {
    A<int>* a = static_cast<A<int>*>(arg);
    a->aMember();
}
```

If `run` can operate on different `A` instantiations, and need not worry about others, `run` itself can be a template:

```
template <typename T>
void *run(void *arg) {
    A<T>* a = static_cast<A<T>*>(arg);
    a->aMember();
}

pthread_create(..., ..., &run<int>, &a);
```

If `run` needs to operate uniformly on any type, this is not possible. You can, however, factor out the common type-independent interface, and refer to a *non-template* base:

```
class ABase {
public:
    // functionality present regardless of template argument
    virtual void aMember() = 0;

    // polymorphic bases should always have virtual destructors
    virtual ~ABase() {}
};

template <typename T>
class A : public ABase {
public:
    void aMember() { /* use type information */ }
};

void *run(void *arg) {
    ABase* a = static_cast<ABase*>(arg);
    a->aMember(); // dynamic dispatch
}
```